# What is the correct way set NumberFomatterFactory to a JFormattedTextField?

Tags: java, swing, numberformatexception, jformattedtextfield

I am using the following code to set NumberFomatterFactory to a JFormattedTextField :

```
    try{
    JFormattedTextField ccyTxt = new JFormattedTextField();
    DecimalFormat ccyTxtFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
    ccyTxtFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits((int) 13);
    ccyTxtFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits((int) 5);
    ccyTxtFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(0);
    ccyTxtFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
    NumberFormatter ccyTxtFormatter = new NumberFormatter(ccyTxtFormat);
    ccyTxtFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(true);
    DefaultFormatterFactory ccyTxtDecimalFormatterFactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(ccyTxtFormatter);
    ccyTxt.setFormatterFactory(ccyTxtDecimalFormatterFactory);
    } catch(Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
    }
```

But, getting exception as follows:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot format given Object as a Number
        at java.text.DecimalFormat.format(DecimalFormat.java:487)
        at java.text.Format.format(Format.java:140)
```

What is the correct way set NumberFomatterFactory to a JFormattedTextField?

Comment: 1) Please learn common Java nomenclature (naming conventions - e.g. `EachWordUpperCaseClass`, `firstWordLowerCaseMethod()`, `firstWordLowerCaseAttribute` unless it is an `UPPER_CASE_CONSTANT`) and use it consistently. 2) Use a logical and consistent form of indenting code lines and blocks.  The indentation is intended to make the flow of the code easier to follow! 3) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

I am unable to reproduce the exception you report; it's not clear why you catch `Exception` at all. The complete example below may help you study the problem in isolation. In particular,

- Adding a second component will allow you to see the effect of a change in focus.
- Use `setColumns()` to specify an initial size.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.text.DecimalFormat;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.text.DefaultFormatterFactory;
import javax.swing.text.NumberFormatter;

/**
 * @see http://stackoverflow.com/a/37807744/230513
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));

        JFormattedTextField ccyTxt = new JFormattedTextField();
        DecimalFormat ccyTxtFormat = (DecimalFormat) DecimalFormat.getNumberInstance();
        ccyTxtFormat.setMaximumIntegerDigits((int) 13);
        ccyTxtFormat.setMaximumFractionDigits((int) 5);
        ccyTxtFormat.setMinimumIntegerDigits(0);
        ccyTxtFormat.setMinimumFractionDigits(0);
        NumberFormatter ccyTxtFormatter = new NumberFormatter(ccyTxtFormat);
        ccyTxtFormatter.setAllowsInvalid(true);
        DefaultFormatterFactory CcyTxtDecimalFormatterFactory = new DefaultFormatterFactory(ccyTxtFormatter);
        ccyTxt.setFormatterFactory(CcyTxtDecimalFormatterFactory);
        ccyTxt.setColumns(12);

        f.add(ccyTxt);
        f.add(new JButton("Button"));
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Test()::display);
    }
}
```